# How to create login functionality in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, session, laravel

Hi, I'm pretty new to laravel. I was asked to create the application in Laravel. Now initially, I am working on the Login Module.

**Basic Requirement**

- Show the login page as landing page when user is logged in.
- After giving the user credentials, session should set and user must redirect to inner pages.
- After successful login, login page should not be displayed, unless logged out.

So for checking the login status, I used the filters in filters.php like below.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // $myApp Singleton object
    App::singleton('myApp', function(){
        $app = new stdClass;
        $app->title = "APD | Dealership Invoicing";
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $app->user = Auth::User();
            $app->isLogedin = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $app->isLogedin = FALSE;
            $app->user = FALSE;
        }
        return $app;
    });
    $app = App::make('myApp');
    View::share('myApp', $app);
});
```

I implemented the above code based on the blog posted in the " http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout#.VH280nvB25s ".

And when user clicks on Login button from view, I am sending the data to controller and checking the db for the data and if the data is correct then I am putting the user details in session and redirecting to the internal pages.

**Controller Code**

```
public function validateLogin()
{
    $data = Input::all();
    $user_data = $this->validate_user_login($data);
    if(is_array($user_data) && !empty($user_data) && count($user_data) > 0)
    {
        /* The below conversion is used, because there seems to be difficulty in returning the Arrays from the Eloquent ORM.*/
        $user_array = (array)$user_data[0];
        Session::put('user_data', $user_array);            
        return Redirect::to('/jobs');
    }
}
```

**Route.php Code**

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    #return View::make('login/login');
    return Redirect::to('/login');
});

Route::get('/login', 'UserController@login');

Route::post('/user/validate_login', 'UserController@validateLogin');

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::get('/jobs', 'JobsController@jobs_list');
});
```

But my problem is, the redirection is taking me back to the login page.

**Questions**

- How can I set the logged-in status as true after login?
- How can I initiate the Session. I set the session key in the controller, is that enough to validate the user session?
- In future I have to develop REST APIs for the same, I have to use the same application for both, web and services platforms. So based on that putting the control in the filters make any difficulty in API calls?
- Where can I find the Auth class and Check function in "Auth::Check()"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved login functionality by using the tutorial by Jeffrey in "https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/15". It is simple great explanation. I have changed the code which was written by me with the way Jeffrey explained. It worked great.

I'll give brief login functionality, I built after the video.

**Router File**

```
Router.php
----------

/* This route is used to show the login page, when there is no session created.*/

Route::group(array('before' => 'login'), function()
{
    Route::get('login', 'UserController@create');
});

/* This below route is used when user is clicked on the login button in the log in page. */

Route::post('/user/store','UserController@store');
```

**Filter File**

```
Filter.php
----------
App::before(function($request)
{
    // $myApp Singleton object
    App::singleton('myApp', function(){
        $app = new stdClass;
        $app->title = "APD | Dealership Invoicing";
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $app->user = Auth::User();
            $app->isLogedin = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $app->isLogedin = FALSE;
            $app->user = FALSE;
        }
        return $app;
    });
$app = App::make('myApp');
View::share('myApp', $app);
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    /* The below headers are used to restrict the browser to cache the pages.           
    */
    $response->headers->set("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate");
    $response->headers->set("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    $response->headers->set("Expires"," Sat, 26 Jul 1986 05:00:00 GMT");
});

/*
| Authentication Filters    
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            /*return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);*/
            return Response::make('common.unauthorized');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller File**

```
UserController.php
------------------
/**
 * The below function is used to show the login screen.
 */
public function create()
{
    /*
       This helps us to restrict the display of login page when clicked on browser back button after login.
    */

    $headers = array();
    $headers['Expires'] = 'Tue, 1 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT';
    $headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0';
    $headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';

    return Response::make(View::make('login.login'), 200, $headers);
    //return View::make('login.login');
}    

public function store()
{
    $input_data = Input::all();
    $credentials = array(
        'user_name' => htmlEncode(trim($input_data['user_name'])),
        'password' => $input_data['password'],
        'status' => 1
    );

    /* Here I am calling a function in the parent class. My UserController is extending the BaseController. The code will be available below. */

    $loginStatus = $this->validateUserLogin($credentials);

    if($loginStatus['status'] == 200)
    {
        $roleId = Auth::User()->role_id;
        $loggedInUserId = Auth::User()->id;
        $redirectPage = '/products';
        switch ($roleId)
        {
            case 'super':
                $redirectPage = '/manage_users';
                break;
            case 'admin':
                $redirectPage = '/products';
                break;                
        }
        return Redirect::to($redirectPage);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('status_data',$loginStatus);
    }
}
```

**Base Controller File**

```
BaseController.php
------------------

protected function validateUserLogin($userData = '')
{
    $this->return_array = array();        
    if(!empty($userData))
    {
        if(Auth::attempt($userData))
        {
            $this->return_array['status'] = 200;
            $this->return_array['message'] = 'Login successfull.';
        }
        else
        {
            $userData['status'] = 0;
            if(Auth::validate($userData)) // This is to verify weather user is existed with status '0'. That means De-active user.
            {
                $this->return_array['status'] = 100;
                $this->return_array['message'] = 'Your account is deactivated, Please contact your admin.';
            }
            else
            {
                $this->return_array['status'] = 100;
                $this->return_array['message'] = 'Login failed. Please enter valid user name and password.';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->return_array['status'] = 100;
        $this->return_array['message'] = 'Unable to login please try after some time.';
    }

    return $this->return_array;
}
```

Comment: I have coppied this code but Auth::check() is not working for me